# Real Analysis- Convergence sequences: Choice/Restriction of Epsilon?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

[image]

In example 2.2 part 2, the author makes two restrictions because according to him we are making n approach infinity twice. The first with the numerator, and the second with the denominator. My first question is will this ALWAYS be the case whenever we have more than one sequence term in an equation? That is placing restrictions for multiple Epsilons per each sequence term?

My second question concerns his choice of restrictions. Letting Epsilon be greater than 0 for the numerator is just standard procedure, but why in the world is he making Epsilon = 1 for the denominator?

Thanks for any info,  all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first question, in general, yes, if our expression has several $x_n$'s, then we should deal several times with the fact that $n$ is going to infinity.

Concerning the other question, any $\varepsilon\in(0,2)$ would do and $\varepsilon=1$ is just the more natural choice. But if we take, say, $\varepsilon=\frac23$, that will work too. In that case, we will have that$$\lvert x_n\rvert=\bigl\lvert2+(x_n-2)\bigr\rvert\geqslant2-\frac23=\frac43.$$

Comment: That is an excellent explanation, Jose!!

Comment: Perhaps it is due to my fundamental lack of understanding what these restrictions are (or what their purpose is) that is the source of my confusion. Must each restriction be different per xsub-n term? Because if not then I certainly do not understand why the author didn't just let epsilon be greater than zero for both terms. And lastly, why must epsilon only be bounded from (0,2)? Thanks for any help

Comment: You have to take $\varepsilon\in(0,2)$ because otherwise you have no positive value $K$ such that each $\lvert x_n\rvert$ is greater than $K$ (for instance, in my example, $K=\frac43$).